# IC BP9916C Block Diagram

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, datasheet, lamp

Could you explain the functioning of each block in the IC BP9916C block diagram?

[image: IC BP9916C]

datasheet :https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/1086203/BPS/BP9916C/1

Answer (score 1):

This is Non-Isolated Buck LED Driver. The function of each blocks can be found in the datasheet page 5-7.

The VCC power supply block is an internal HV switch buck converter that will charge the external capacitor to supply the IC at around 7 volt. There also undervoltage protection and control scheme incorporated with the VCC supply.

CC & logic control were the part that the device main function as LED driver. There is Constant Current (CC) regulation that controlled by logic. The CC itself is using CS pin to provide current sense. Therefore, close loop CC regulation is used in this IC. CC & logic control provide switching trigger to the internal MOSFET to control the LED.

Comment: what is LEB? and what it do ?

Comment: It seems it used for leading edge blanking time control feedback

Comment: how about the ZCD? What it do?

Comment: In this case, it seems it is a zero cross detector to detect buck inductor current. As stated in the datasheet: "After the power MOSFET is switched off, the current in the inductor decreases. When the inductor current reaches zero, the power MOSFET is turned on again by IC internal logic.".

Comment: i don't get it.

Comment: The ZCD is merely connected to the gate of mosfet right? So how does the ZCD detect buck inductor current?

Comment: ZCD commonly used in CCM/DCM buck converters. Since it is a Buck LED Driver, it use same principle to control the switching of internal MOSFET. ZCD detect and give information to logic control block if the current reach zero and initiate internal MOSFET switching.

Comment: ZCD of inductor current can be done with various way. Please take a note that the block diagram that given by manufacturer is simplified. Therefore, I can't tell you what exact manufacturer does in this IC.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I repaired a LED lamp with this driver, and did some research about it.
I simulated to understand more deeply how it could work. Many users of this stack have great knowledge and could give better ideas, but these circuits will help you to understand a little more.
[image]
It is a critical buck cc driver, the current through the inductor charges a a capacitor to feed the LED chain. So basically it is a flip flop (A1) that controls the gate of an NMOS-FET (SW_NMOS); L current zero will set the SR, when L current gets over the peak limit, will be reset. It is a triangular shape wave, so the average is half of the current peak.
[image]

Power supply comes from Drain pin, through a HV JFET (as constant current source); it charges an external capacitor C4 connected at Vcc pin. A comparator (U3) switches off when voltage is over 7.2 V, switch on under this limit. I did not find a convenient JFET, so a used a NMOS with negative Vto (-4V); through R10 will give about 2 mA. Whenever Vcc is below a limit (UV), the SR will be reset, and a pulse (C8 & R11) is used to start operation if it reaches the turn on threshold.

One tricky block is ZCD, as L1 discharge current doesn´t flow by any pin of the driver. After SW_NMOS switches off, L1 current will flow through D1, so voltage of drain pin will Vrect+VD1drop. Once the energy of L1 has been extinguished, there will be no voltage through L1, so Drain pin will be at lower voltage: Vrect-VC1. If you hold the Drain voltage with a diode and a small capacitor, using a comparator to detect a lower voltage of this pin, will determine the zero current status. I connected a capacitor C11 to delay a little time and see better this intermediate voltage detection.
[image]

Current sensing could be done very easily with a resistor and comparator, but there is no ground pin. It is necessary to sample and hold the voltage from Vcc and CS pin in a capacitor C10, minus a voltage reference 0.6V (V5). When the MOSFET is switched on, S2 will disconnect low side of C10. As current increases through Rcs, the voltage of this pin will rise. The peak current 160 mA will drop 0.6 V at Rcs, over this point the comparator V+ input will be over C10 low side voltage, and comparator U4 will change the output (CS_off).
[image]

Some small RC´s were necessary to avoid very small time step of simulation; also comparators are connected to auxiliary voltage and ground to lower simulation load, but should supplied from Vcc and CS. Comparator U3 have a positive feedback to make switching slower (again, lower simulation load).

Comment: Thank you so much